# Using Metadata/Inheritance to factor out code across multiple classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metadata, metaprogramming

I have two classes that will represent two very simple databases, and each has a "Save" function which will write what's in the class to a file. Since the code within the "Save" function is very similar, I was wondering if I could factor it out.

One of my colleagues said this might be possible with inheritance and/or metadata, so I tried looking into it myself with Google. However, I couldn't find anything that was helpful and am still unsure if what I want to do is even possible.

If it's possible to factor out, then I think I'd need to have another class or function know about each class's types and iterate through them somehow (metadata?). It would check the type of every data, and depending on what the type is, it would make sure that it's correctly output to the text file.

(I know data like name, age, etc. should be private, but to keep this simple I just had everything be public)

```
class A
{
public:
  A() : name(""), age(0) {};

  void Save(void)
  {
    std::string filename = "A.txt";
    std::string data;

    data += name                + "\n";
    data += std::to_string(age) + "\n";

    std::ofstream outfile(filename);
    outfile.write(data.c_str(), data.size());
    outfile.close();
  }

  std::string name;
  int age;
};

class B
{
public:
  B() : ID(0), points(0) {};

  void Save(void)
  {
    std::string filename = "B.txt";
    std::string data;

    data += std::to_string(ID)     + "\n";
    data += std::to_string(points) + "\n";

    std::ofstream outfile(filename);
    outfile.write(data.c_str(), data.size());
    outfile.close();
  }

  int ID;
  int points;
};

int main(void)
{
  A a;
  B b;

  a.name = "Bob"; a.age    = 20;
  b.ID   = 4;     b.points = 95;

  a.Save();
  b.Save();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization): saving objects to a file (and one day or another, restore the objects).

Of course, you could write your own serialization framework, and Marco's answer is an interesting start in that direction.  But alternatively, you could consider existing libraries, such as [`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) :

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class A {
private: 
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & name;
        ar & age;
    }
...
};
class B {
private: 
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & ID;
        ar & points;
    }
...
};
main() {
   A a; 
   B b; 
   ...
   {
      std::ofstream ofs("myfile");
      boost::archive::text_oarchive arch(ofs);
      arch << a << b;
   }
}
```

As you see, it's still needed to say what's to be written to the file.  However, the code is simplified : you don't have to worry about file management and transformation of data.  And it works also with standard containers.

You won't find a C++ trick that automatically determines for a class what's to be saved.  Two reasons for that:

- C++ allows metaprogramming, but it is not reflexive: there are no standard process to find out at execution time which members compose a class.
- In an object, some data can be transient, i.e. it means only something at the time of the execution and depends on the context.  For example pointers:  you could save the value of a pointer to a file, but it will mean nothing when you reload it later (the pointer is only valid until you free the object). The proper way would be to save the object that is pointed to (but where, when, how?).

Comment: both answers are really helpful, shame that I can only pick one. Thanks to both you and Marco

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to use metaprogramming (not sure what you mean by metadata), i.e. templates to reuse the common parts

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void TSave(const std::string fname, const T1& p1, const T2& p2) {
    std::string filename = fname;
    std::stringstream data;

    data << p1 << "\n";
    data << p2 << "\n";

    std::ofstream outfile(filename);
    outfile.write(data.str().c_str(), data.str().size());
    outfile.close();
}

class A {
  ...

  void Save(void) {
    TSave("A.txt", name, age);
  }

  std::string name;
  int age;
};

class B {
  ...

  void Save(void) {
    TSave("B.txt", ID, points);
  }

  int ID;
  int points;
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ae520a71fed5b0e)</kbd>

Comment: Very nice.  Could you elaborate, and propose a version which can have more arguments instead of a fixed number of 2 ?

Comment: @Christophe I have no idea how many additional arguments you might need. It should be pretty straightforward to add more arguments or using a [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

Comment: I don't know how many arguments the OP may have.  But it would be rather improbable that it's always exactly 2...  I hoped you would show how to do it with variadics.  But never mind, [here's](http://ideone.com/wmuZOq)  an example